# LINUX commands in Python

Tags: python, linux, psql

Please help, I am trying to execute the following code to load data from a table into a file

```
import os

schema_src = 'public'
table_src = 'vis_fos_user_user'
connect_resh = os.system('psql -d xxxx -h xxxx.xxxx.xxx -p xxxx -U xxxxxx -w "K7QyOF)D"')
load_to_file = os.system(f'''\copy (SELECT * FROM {schema_src}.{table_src} WHERE {table_src}.updated_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND {table_src}.update_at <= '2022-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) to "/home/airflow/fos_user_user/data_csv_user.csv" csv delimiter ";" header;''')
print(connect_resh)
print(load_to_file)
```

Throws the following error:
psql: предупреждение: лишний аргумент "K7QyOF)D" проигнорирован
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tell me what's the problem

Comment: You are trying to run the input intended for `psql` as a separate command. But don't use `os.system`: use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module instead.

Comment: Better yet, stop using `psql` altogether and use a Python library like [`psycopg2`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/).

Answer (score 0):

When you calling `os.system` function with bracket symbols '(' or ')' contained string argument, You have to use escape character in front of the bracket symbols. This is an  ambiguous expression for python interpreter.

Try this

````
connect_resh = os.system('psql -d xxxx -h xxxx.xxxx.xxx -p xxxx -U xxxxxx -w "K7QyOF\)D"')

load_to_file = os.system(f'''\copy \(SELECT * FROM {schema_src}.{table_src} WHERE {table_src}.updated_at >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND {table_src}.update_at <= '2022-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone\) to "/home/airflow/fos_user_user/data_csv_user.csv" csv delimiter ";" header;''')```
````